# Google search console after DNS IP change crawl dropped to 0

Tags: seo, google-search-console, web-hosting

We recently upgraded our Go Daddy servers on to a faster one. The new faster servers had a different IP address but our domain name had to stay the same. So we pointed the old domain to the new IP address on the faster servers and moved all the old site files to the new one. By doing this our google search console showed a crash on crawl and organic search. We are no longer getting any crawls and our organic search went to 0.

The old server was never turned off just in case if something goes wrong. The website is built with WordPress and on the old one, it no longer works for some reason because the domain has changed probably. The old verification meta is still on the old website it's also added on to the new website. From my assumption google is still picking up the data from the old website on the old IP.

Is this what's possibly case? How can I resolve this issue without losing my SEO ranking?

Screenshot and related information:
[image: Fetch Report]
Fetching it shows redirect instead of the normal complete that you expect to see.

[image: Crawl Status]
Crawl status shows a crash on the day we migrated to the new server, on April 20th.

[image: Crawl Errors]
The only crawl errors shown are 404s. These files are unimportant and don't exist because we removed them. These errors already existed before 4/20 our migration date.

Comment: How long ago did you change it? Does the search console indicate any problems crawling your site?

Comment: We changed it on April 20th, 2018. The only errors are 404 not found and they existed before the migration date, so I am not sure if they are the issue. I have updated with some screenshots, if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: You said you moved to a faster server, however your second screenshot  shows Googlebot is taking significantly longer to download pages from your site following the move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure your website doesn't have a www to non-www or vice versa redirect issue.
That's the case for such issues and Google will be redirected from non-www to www version while you request the non-www version pages to be crawled (or vice-versa again).

Comment: I think this may been the problem. May explain why everything is being redirected. I have added a non www version and it seems to be fetching it properly. I will keep an I on this one to see if the correct stats come back